# Push notification in c# web application project

Tags: c#, notifications, push, web

I have used json to get better performance for my data result of any search in textbox.
I want include Push notification feature ,to show instant update It may be from any browser or any other IP.
It takes notification from server and show instant update without reloading the web page.

Answer (score 6):

You can poll data from server with an interval or you might use some async methods like

node.js or signalR. Mr Hanselman has some great posts about them.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: Thanks for valuable time and feedback

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull in intervals your server for new data.

Setup a timer with the `setinterval` function and call a server function via ajax to look for new data.

Comment: This is not good solution - it is a lot of unnecessary communication.